# Method for Constructing Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm writing a bachelor thesis about Poisson Processes, and I need a method for the construction of these processes.

I know that I can construct them defining inter-arrival times with the exponential distribution, but this method don't work with inhomogeneous processes.
Someone can help me?

Comment: By "construct" a process you mean numerically generate some realization (i.e. simulate it) ?

Answer (score 8):

You can first generate a "canonical" Poisson process with constant intensity $\lambda=1$  and then construct your desired inhomogeneous process by remapping the "time", see [here](http://www.stanley.bme.gatech.edu/courses/BMED8813_web/notes/BMED8813_point_process.pdf), section 5.

Answer (score 4):

In the case you're interested in the straightforward algorithm [this](http://www.im.pwr.wroc.pl/~burnecki/Simulation_of_counting_processes.pdf) can be useful for you. There is given a step by step algorithm together with an explanation.